# Linux: Export global variable of executable to be used in my shared library (C language)

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries

I want to access the global variable of executable in shared library? I have tried to compile using option -export-dynamic  but no luck.

I have tried with extern key word. this also not working.

Any help or suggestion would be appreciable.

Environment c - Linux

executable:- 
tst.c

```
int tstVar = 5;

void main(){
funInso();
    printf("tstVar %d", tstVar);
}
```

lib:-
tstLib.c

```
extern int tstVar;

void funInso(){
   tstVar = 50;
}
```

Since my code is very big, I just gave the sample which I have used in my program.

Comment: How did you try `extern` keyword?. It works. Show us the code.

Comment: @TioPepe  I just added the sample code :)

Comment: What's the problems you have? What, if any, error messages do you get? How do you build the library? How do you build the executable?

Answer (score 3):

It should work. BTW, your `tst.c`is lacking a `#include <stdio.h>`. And its `main` should return an `ìnt` and end with e.g. `return 0;`.

With

```
/* file tst.c */
#include <stdio.h>
int tstVar = 5;
extern void funInso(void);

int main(){
  funInso();
  printf("tstVar %d\n", tstVar);
  return 0;
}
```

and

```
/* file tstlib.c */
extern int tstVar;

void funInso(){
   tstVar = 50;
}
```

I compiled with `gcc -Wall -c tst.c` the first file, I compiled with `gcc -Wall -c tstlib.c` the second file. I made it a library with

```
 ar r libtst.a tstlib.o
 ranlib libtst.a
```

Then I linked the first file to the library with  `gcc -Wall tst.o -L. -ltst -o tst`

The common practice is to have with your library a header file `tstlib.h` which would contain e.g.

```
 #ifndef TSTLIB_H_
 #define TSTLIB_H_
 /* a useful explanation about tstVar.  */
 extern int tstVar;

 /* the role of funInso. */
 extern void funInso(void);
 #endif /*TSTLIB_H */
```

and have both `tst.c` and `tstlib.c` contain an `#include "tstlib.h"`

If the library is shared, you should

1. compile the library file in position independent code mode

   ```
   gcc -Wall -fpic -c tstlib.c -o tstlib.pic.o
   ```
2. link the library with `-shared`

   ```
   gcc -shared tstlib.pic.o -o libtst.so
   ```

   Note that you can link a shared object with other libraries. You could have appended `-lgdbm` to that command, if your `tstlib.c` is e.g. calling `gdbm_open` hence including `<gdbm.h>`. This is one of the many features shared libraries give you that static libraries don't.
3. link the executable with `-rdynamic`

   ```
   gcc -rdynamic tst.o -L. -ltst -o tst
   ```

Please take time to read the [Program Library Howto](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/)

Answer (score 0):

The `int myVariable = 123;` syntax should already work, because unlike MSVC, you never need `__declspec(dllexport)` keywords.

But if you changed compiler's default settings, try setting `visibility` manually, see example.

### Example

In app's (not lib's) header:

```
// Backward compatible header recurse guard.
#ifndef MY_APP_H
#define MY_APP_H

// MARK: Helpers.
#define MY_APP_EXPORT __attribute__((visibility("default")))

// MARK: Variables.
MY_APP_EXPORT extern int myVariable;
MY_APP_EXPORT extern int myOtherVariable;

#endif // MY_APP_H
```

In app's (not lib's) source:

```cpp
#include "my-app.h"

int myVariable = 123;
int myOtherVariable = 786;

int main() {

    // ...

    return 0; // Success.
}
```

Finally, your lib should **not** copy-paste the App's declarations, and should instead use App's header directly.

Answer (score -1):

your  tstVar variable could be defined in the lib. and you can share this variable via functions:
`setFunction`: to edit this variable

```
void setFunction (int v)
{
    tstVar = v;
}
```

`getFunction`: to return the variable

```
int getFunction ()
{
    return tstVar
}
```